"Bad Request" when deploying to my Azure Function using Bicep
I am trying to roll out an Azure Function with bicep. Everything up to 'Microsoft.Web/sites' and everything around it (Blob and such) works and I can use VS Code to deploy my python code to that function afterwards.
When I try to deploy my code using Bicep aswell, I get the following error:
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": ""
    }
}

What did I do wrong? I am using a Flex consumption plan and my bicep code for 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions' is below.
resource function 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions@2020-12-01' = {
  parent: functionApp
  name: functionNameComputed
  properties: {
    config: {
      scriptFile: 'function_app.py' // tried with and without this option
      entryPoint: 'function_app'    // tried with and without this option
      disabled: false
      bindings: [
        {
          name: 'req'
          type: 'httpTrigger'
          direction: 'in'
          authLevel: 'function'
          methods: [
            'get'
          ]
        }
        {
          name: '$return'
          type: 'http'
          direction: 'out'
        }
      ]
    }
    files: {
      'function_app.py': loadTextContent('function_app.py')
      'requirements.txt': loadTextContent('requirements.txt')
    }
  }
}


What is the exact error message you are getting? @Dave4048

@Jahnavi unfortunately that was the whole and only error message I got.

The issue "Bad request" error seems to be because of flex consumption plan function app. There are some limitations in bicep related to the scaling up the instances and memory wise with the flex consumption app while deploying the functions which are listed here in MSDoc and also refer the same document for deploying Python function into flex consumption plan app using CLI.
And when I tried to deploy the same function using functions premium plan, it was successfully deployed without any conflicts. I would suggest you using a dedicated app service plan or a consumption or premium plan fits in this scenario.
I have executed the same code as you have, shown below.
resource funcp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' existing = {
  name: 'appplanj'
}
resource function 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions@2023-12-01' = {
  parent: funcp
  name: 'funcpytrigger'
  properties: {
    config: {
      bindings: [
        {
          name: 'req'
          type: 'httpTrigger'
          direction: 'in'
          authLevel: 'function'
          methods: [
            'get'
          ]
        }
        {
          name: '$return'
          type: 'http'
          direction: 'out'
        }
      ]
    }
      files:{
        'function_app.py': loadTextContent('function_app.py') 
        'requirements.txt': loadTextContent('requirements.txt')
    }
  }

Deployment succeeded:


Note: Instead of bicep, use CLI or visual studio code deployment feature for deploying the python azure functions to flex consumption plan apps.

Due to costs and my specific needs, Flex Consumption is the only viable option. I deployed it now using VS Code as a workaround. This was not an elegant solution because I had to change the networking settings in order to access the function. I will have a look at the CLI. Thanks for your help.

Is CLI command works for your deployment. @Dave4048

Even though documentation still is saying that "Continuous deployment using Azure DevOps Tasks (AzureFunctionApp@2)" is not yet supported for Flex consumption, the task AzureFunctionApp@2 actually was updated to support this.
Documentation on AzureFunctionApp@2:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-function-app-v2?view=azure-pipelines
